# GDB doesn't start

Tags: c++, gdb, antivirus, tdm-gcc

Today I have run QtCreator to make a simple console app and experienced a problem. The project builds OK, then "Launching a Debugger" starts, but, unfortunately, doesn't finish. I see console with cursor and the program is not running.
Trying Helloworld sample - same result. Trying helloworld sample in Code Blocks - same. I have even tried to compile through the command line (`g++ -g hworld.cpp -o hworld.exe`). Then `gdb hworld.exe`, `run` - the same. Nothing happens, just cursor blinks.
I have already tried to reinstall all this staff (C::B, Qt, TDM-GCC) but it doesn't help.
May be the reason is Oracle MySQL for Windows which I installed few days ago. I used MySQL Installer 5.7.12, it installs a lot of different staff.
I would appreciate help very much, because it's really a trouble and I don't know what to do. I need both MySQL and C++ IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is found, it was Avast Free Antivirus 2015.
It was surprising for me because I have been using this antivirus already for 2 months and never had problems. I'm really sure, Avast is the reason, because if I turn it off the problem vanishes. When I turn it on, the problem is here again.
I've upgraded to Avast Free Antivirus 2016, now everything's fine.
Also, a good idea is to add the projects' directory to the antivirus exceptions.